# How to display other text based on data getting from server in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, hide, show

How can I display some other text or icon based on data getting from server, here I am getting these following data from sever, and for all false parameter I want display some other text instead of false, if there false then I want to display some cross icon and if there is true then I want to display success icon,
this is screen shot of my data
[image]

And this is my function to show data

```
showPrice= () => {
debugger;
if (this.state.priceList !== undefined) {
  return this.state.priceList.map(price => {


    return (

      <tr>
        <td>{price.premiumname}</td>
        <td>dfdf</td>
        <td>{price.expired_time}</td>
        <td>{price.inrprice}</td>

    <td>{price.entertainmentvideo }</td>
        </td>}
        <td>{price.accesslesson}</td>
        <td>{price.exerciselesson}</td>
        <td>{price.lsystem}</td>
        <td>{price.vocabulary}</td>
        <td>{price.materialdownload}</td>
        <td>{price.exclusivewebinars}</td>
        <td>{price.tutoring}</td>
        <td>{price.conversation}</td>
        <td>{price.subscribtion}</td>
        <td>
```

Please help me I am new to Reacts
Thanks

Comment: provide error info.
Are you updating the state in render method?

Comment: your error tells you that you are trying to update state so many times that hits a limit. I guess you are trying to update it on each render?

Comment: There is a problem with your `render` method content, somewhere it contains a call for a function that is envoked without a controller and uses `setState`. this causes the state to render multiple time during the first cycle of mounting your component, verify your `render` method, and find out which of the function is causing this behaviour, if you edit the question with the rest of your component's code we may be able to help.

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume the following state, that get's updated after an API's call in `componentDidMount`:

```
state = { data : null }

componentDidMount(){
     APICall().then(data => this.setState({ data })) 
}
```

Now you just need to render the text based on the state's property. For example:

```
render(){
    <>
        !this.state.data ? <p>Loading</p> : <p>Loaded</p>
    </> 
}
```

Comment: Yes I just need to display data based on property

Comment: `{this.state.entertainmentvideo === "false" ?  <td><i class="ti-trash"></i></td>:<td><i class="ti-close"></i></td>}`

Comment: if entertainmentvide ="false" then I want to display sometext if =="true" then I want display some other text